# WPF Converting selected value from checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question I have a combobox in WPF that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          commands:PropertyChangeBehavior.Command="{Binding GetCurrentsModuleCommand}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModule, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="True" Content="All">
                <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ModulesCombo}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Now source is just a list of ints, but I need some default value so I've added that `ComboBoxItem`. Now selected item property looks like:

```
    private int selectedModule;

    public int SelectedAModule
    {
        get => selectedModule;
        set
        {
            selectedModule = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

When changing to default value I am getting

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: All' from type 'ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.Int32'

And if I check command:

```
    public ICommand GetCurrentsModuleCommand => new Command(module =>
    {
        SomeLogic();
    });
```

If it is a normal value module is a number, but if it all value I am getting:

```
"System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: All";
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of binding to a `Dictionary` as suggested by @Ann Mary is a viable solution (+1).

You may also use a custom value converter that knows how to convert a `ComboBoxItem` to an `int`:

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = value as ComboBoxItem;
        if (cbi != null)
            return cbi.Tag;

        return value;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="SelectedModule" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:Converter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="True" Content="All">
                <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ModulesCombo}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to bind to Dictionary where Key is selected int and value is label of ComboBox item:

```
 public Dictionary<int, string> dic { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            [0] = "All",
            [1] = "1",
            [2] = "2"
        };
```

Property with selected value:

```
public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
```

Next, you can create ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    ItemsSource="{Binding dic}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

DisplayMemberPath is Value from dictionary which will be displayed in ComboBox, SelectedValue is int property where you want to store selected index and SelectedValuePath is Key from dictionary (this will be stored in SelectedValue after select something in ComboBox)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a `ComboBoxItem` to your `CompositeCollection`. The work of `CompositeCollection` is to merge lists and single items into one collection. In your case you are merging list of integers and one `ComboBoxItem` which tag's value is integer. To add `0` to the list just replace `ComboBoxItem` with integer in `CompositeCollection`

```
<CompositeCollection>
   <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
   <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ModulesCombo}}" />
</CompositeCollection>
```

If you need to change text for that item you can use [DateTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx). In `DataTemplateSelector` you can use one `DataTemplate` for `0` value and another `DataTemplate` for non `0` values.